# Generating SSHFP record from OpenSSH known_hosts file entry

Tags: ssh, known-hosts

I have an entry from an OpenSSH `known_hosts` file; I'd like to generate an SSHFP resource record for this. I can use `ssh-keygen` to generate the fingerprint with no difficulty:

```
$ ssh-keygen -f foo_known_host -l
1040 09:a0:5c:5f:43:fb:e5:25:d8:0c:d8:dc:d7:7a:c4:62 foo.example.com. (RSA)
```

But it doesn't seem to like it for a DNS fingerprint record:

```
$  ssh-keygen -f foo_known_host -r foo
failed to read v2 public key from foo_known_host.
```

So how do I do this?

---

**Note:** If you came here via asking a search engine how to generate an SSHFP record *from a remote host* (not a local copy of the fingerprint as above), that's done via `ssh-keyscan -D machine.name –`.

Comment: If the question that brought you here is "How do I generate an SSHFP record from a remote machine (like a router)" the answer is: ssh-keyscan -D machine.name

Comment: @GrahamLeggett No; that is not my question. As I state in my question above, I want to do this from a `known_hosts` file entry, not by accessing the remote machine.

Comment: I know that is not your question, as I made clear in the comment above. Google however is not good at distinguishing between similar questions, thus the comment above.

Comment: @GrahamLeggett Oh, I thought the comment was aimed at me, not others reading this question. I understand the issue you're trying to fix now, and have updated the question with your note, which I hope will help with this. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 2):

[`ssh-keygen(1)`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh-keygen) doesn't behave the same way as [`sshfp(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sshfp).

You'll note from the man page that the syntax is:

```
ssh-keygen -r hostname [-f input_keyfile] [-g]
```

So the file should be an `input_keyfile` rather than a `known_hosts_file`. If you don't specify then it will default to the server's local keys of `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub` and `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key.pub`.

You can either generate the record from each server that you wish to create SSHFP records for with `ssh-keygen`. Or source `sshfp` and create them all from one `known_hosts` file.

Answer (score 0):

This script is good:

http://brmlab.cz/kb/sshfp.sh

It needs to be run in /etc/ssh, or edit it to cd there before it does it's stuff.

Answer (score -1):

try -r $HOSTNAME as first arguement:

```
$ ssh-keygen -r moppel -f ~/.ssh/id_dsa -g
moppel IN TYPE44 \# 22 02 01 3950bf0c2cf2318b9ab2187992b6f7869947c3aa
```

Comment: No, switching around the arguments doesn't work. You got probably got correct output because you gave it a v2 public key file, not a known_hosts file with one entry.